# Nametags skip first row and spill over [solved]

Tags: civievent

I have created a profile for nametags that seems fairly normal: organization logo, blank line (10 pt), First name (24 pt bold), Last Name (24 pt bold), Organization Name (14 pt).

What results is a blank row of two nametags with the graphic but no names.  And at the bottom is an extra row of names that spills off the page.

What might be causing this and how can I fix it?  The mis-match between graphic and names is throwing me.

Comment: could you include a screenshot? not sure what you mean exactly

Comment: [IMG]http://i945.photobucket.com/albums/ad299/vermontrailactionnetwork/Nametag_Problem.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: A screenshot is at that photobucket link.  Seems IMG tags aren't working here and I'm not sure how to attach a screenshot.  But that should work.  Thanks.

Comment: Could it that for the first two participants on the list there is no first name, last name or organization name? Maybe you could test it with the display name

Comment: Alas, there are no blanks in the name fields and that doesn't address the spillover problem.  But thanks.

Comment: Some testing has shown it is something to do with the graphic.  Removing the graphic removes the problem.  Hmmm

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  The graphic was made to be exactly as large as the nametag itself, although most of that size was blank so the names could print over it.  The result was that the first nametag started below the graphic, which happened to be the beginning of the next nametag.

Comment: If this is solved then it would be great to post the answer below [=